# How can I restore Firefox bookmark files from SQLite files?

Tags: sqlite, firefox, bookmarks

I have two files that I managed to restore from a Firefox installation under Windows XP. The first one is urlclassifier3.sqlite and the second one is urlclassifier.pset.

I understand that those files contain the actual bookmarks for an installation of Firefox, under a user profile, given that the profile is .\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\akcum27.default. How can I restore the bookmarks from those files?

The big one is the .sqlite file, at around 56 kilobytes.

Comment: Is this for Firefox prior to version 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bookmarks are held in file `places.sqlite`, not urlclassifier. You can try to replace the file in your current installation with that. Make sure Firefox is closed. If that doesn't work:

You might want to install the Firefox addon "SQLite Manager" and then use the addon (use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to open the addon menu in Firefox) to open the file places.sqlite from your old install. Right click *Tables* -> *moz_bookmarke* on the left hand side and click "export table"

Export your table as XML or SQL and then open file places.sqlite from your current install and click *Database* -> *Import Table* and import it in the similiar same way you exported.

Comment: Nice. I think I will install this SQLite Manager soon. But I could not find the places.sqlite file anywhere on the laptop. I copied the entire tree from the Mozilla directory, and there is no such file. However, the other sqlite was updated very recently, and was 56K, so I assumed this was the actual file. Can it be that Firefox was using another name in a previous version ?

Comment: "Places.sqlite is used in Firefox 3 and above, instead of the older bookmarks.html and history.dat files (the older files are left in the profile folder for backward compatibility)." From mozzila kb.  As far as to where it is hiding, if you have windows 7 /vista did you check `users\[yourusername]\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[yourprofilesname]` and `users\[yourusername]\local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[yourprofilename]` ?

Comment: Also it claims in the kb article it can be moved without haveing to do the import/export: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite#Moving

Comment: urlclassifier is part of safe browsing, is it not?

Comment: I did not check under .\Roaming\, since there is usually nothing there, but I will check again. As well, since I now have the original full disk, I will mount it externally and search the entire drive. Thanks !!!

Comment: there are plural tables and tables are cross referenced with unique keys. simple merge will result a collide.

Comment: Re *"moz_bookmarke"*: For the German version only?

Answer (score 6):

A query that will actually work (on Windows as the question is about) is:

```
sqlite3 places.sqlite "select '<a href=''' || url || '''>' || moz_bookmarks.title || '</a><br/>' as ahref from moz_bookmarks left join moz_places on fk=moz_places.id where url<>'' and moz_bookmarks.title<>''" > t1.html
```

This presumes:

- Using the Windows command-line (CMD)
- The current directory is where file *places.sqlite* is (there is one for each Firefox profile, with the default profile often named *"default"* or *"default-release"*)
- [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) 3 (executable `sqlite3`) is installed and is in the path (environment variable `PATH`)

Sample generated HTML:

```
<a href='http://www.wunderground.com/hurricane/'>Tropical weather</a><br/>
<a href='http://www.dmi.dk/vejr/maalinger/radar-nedboer/'>DMI, Radar</a><br/>
<a href='http://www.skyandtelescope.com/observing/objects/planets/3304091.html?page=1&c=y'>Transit Times of Jupiter's Great Red Spot - Planets - SkyandTelescope.com</a><br/>
<a href='https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-most-misspelt-word-in-the-English-language'>(951/25) What is the most misspelt word in the English language? - Quora</a><br/>
<a href='http://www.eevblog.com/2015/06/16/eevblog-754-altium-circuit-maker-first-impressions/'>EEVblog #754 - Altium Circuit Maker First Impressions | EEVblog - The Electronics Engineering Video Blog</a><br/>
<a href='https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno'>Arduino - ArduinoBoardUno</a><br/>
```

#### Notes

- The result is not ordered as in the Firefox *Bookmarks* menu, and there are some *extra* entries, both http/https ones, like *"About Us"* and some non-http/https ones.
- SQLite is often installed by other tools, but a simple way to make it work from scratch on Windows is to download the bundle of command-line tools from [the official download page](https://sqlite.org/download.html) ([sample direct download URL](https://sqlite.org/2023/sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3410200.zip)), extract the three files, and copy file *sqlite3.exe* into the profile folder (where file *places.sqlite* is).
- It also works on [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux), but

  - if Firefox is running, the result is *"Error: database is locked"* (for the Firefox profile in question, if more than one Firefox profile is used. E.g., use *about:profiles* in the address bar to explore the profiles). Alternatively, make a copy of file *places.sqlite* and use that instead in the command line
  - SQLite 3 is not installed on [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) systems by default, but it can be installed with:

    ```
    sudo apt install sqlite3
    ```
  - This was verified with [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver) and [Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa)
- It has been known to work on (reverse version order):

  - [Firefox 97.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_version_history#Firefox_91_through_101) (2022-02-08) on Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver)
  - [Firefox 97.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_version_history#Firefox_78_through_90) on (2022-02-08) Ubuntu MATE 20.04 (Focal Fossa)
  - [Firefox 83.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_version_history#Firefox_78_through_90) on (2020-11-17) Ubuntu MATE 20.04 (Focal Fossa)
  - [Firefox 57.0.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_version_history#Firefox_52_through_59) (2017-12-23) on Windows 10. [Quantum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox#Firefox_Quantum). 64-bit version 64-bit)
  - [Firefox 46](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_version_history#Firefox_45_through_51) (2016-04-26)
  - [Firefox 40](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_version_history#Firefox_38_through_44) on Windows (approximately. 2015-08. Before Quantum).

Comment: Firefox 46 and it is still working... ps> my way to thank [ [1](http://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/details.cgi?aid=12021), [2](http://apod.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/apod/apod_search?tquery=+%22great+red+spot%22++Jupiter) ]

Answer (score 3):

You can also replace the `places.sqlite` file in the Firefox profile folder, and then, since the database may not be retrieved by Firefox, you can open another web browser (Chrome, Edge, etc.) and import your Firefox bookmarks from this new browser (most of the browsers can import Firefox bookmarks). Finally, from Firefox you can import the bookmarks again from this third-party web browser.

Answer (score 1):

A quick-and-dirty solution is:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sqlite3 places.sqlite 'select "<a href={" || url || "}>" || moz_bookmarks.title || "</a><br/>" as ahref  from moz_bookmarks left join moz_places on fk=moz_places.id where url<>"" and moz_bookmarks.title<>""' > t1.html
```

Comment: I got "***> was unexpected at this time.***" when I tried it (latest version of SQLite (2015-07) and file "places.sqlite" written by Firefox 40 (2015-08))